# How do I use enumeration flags?

Tags: .net, vb.net, enums

I am confused on how to properly use and combine enumeration flags. Below is an example of the code. If I call `GetCarByColor(CarColor.Blue)` I would expect it to return all cars that have a color of blue, but in this case it returns an empty list because the car in my list is Red or Blue.  How can I properly return the correct list of cars if it is possible for the car to be blue?

```
<Flags>
Public Enum CarColor
    Red = 1
    Green = 2
    Blue= 4
End Enum

Public Class Cars
    Public Property Color as CarColor
End Class

Public Class GetCars
    Private _cars as List(of Car) From {New Car() With {Color = CarColor.Red Or CarColor.Blue}}

    Public Function GetCarByColor(color as CarColor) as List(of Car)
        Return _cars.Where(Function(f) f.Color = color).ToList
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 and later you can use the [Enum HasFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Public Function GetCarByColor(color as CarColor) as List(of Car)
    Return _cars.Where(Function(f) f.Color.HasFlag(color)).ToList()
End Sub
```